# wxPython error message - clicking button for a small image to appear on the canvas within my frame

Tags: python, user-interface, button, wxpython

OK, so iv almost completed my program for my project but I cant get a BUTTON_EVT to work which if i am honest should be the easiest thing todo. I have the buttons on my program which represent the hardware and I have created a def function for them to appear on the OGL canvas.

- Problem has been solved... The code associated with the problem is found in the answer below

Comment: Is that all the code you have. I am going to try it now.

Comment: I have far more code than this...I have just taken snippets out of it to try and explain

Comment: How are you creating mainApp? Can you please write a snippet from there too so that it becomes easier to help.

Comment: I dont no how to send the code through stack overflow but I would quite happily send the code another way if you like?

Comment: You can edit your own post and place your code there.

Comment: Ok, added all the code... sorry if the indentation is out...I always get problems when pasting the code over.... Please bear in mind that the images in my root python file are 35x35 pixels so quite small.

Comment: @karldavies would be more efficient if you simplify your code to the minimal, functional snippet that can be run and reproduces the exception.

Comment: True, I did have a simplified version to begin with but I added the full code on request.

Comment: But now the full version has many things different or commented relative to the first version. In any case, this code (the gui/canvas part) does not work. I did some fixes and I made the gui work with my own pictures. But it doesn't work as you think it does: try adding `self.frame.Show()` in OnClickRouter (you must first to fix the arguments in `self.frame=bucky(image)` and in the bucky class) and you will see that you are creating a new frame although you did not see it because you were not `Show`ing it.

Comment: hmmm...Iv tryed changing a few things and still cant get my head around it. The error message I was getting has now gone but when the image is clicked it doesnt appear, and in the command line shell I get : Attribute Error - 'bucky' object has no attribute 'frame' ...I understand that I am getting this error message because of the arguments in self.frame=bucky(image) but dont no what is really going on. Thanks you for your help mate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited from your last comment**. Use this (using your own images):

```
def OnClickRouter(self, event):
    image=wx.Image('cat.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG)
    self.frame = bucky(None, image)
    self.frame.Show()
```

If you call bucky() this way you must also fix the class signature:

```
class bucky(wx.Frame):      
  # Creating the outer window/frame
  def __init__(self, parent, image=None):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1,'Karls Network Tool', size=(900,700))

    my_image = image if image else wx.Image("myself.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP) 

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    # Button images
    buttonOneRouter = my_image.ConvertToBitmap()
    self.buttonOneRouter = wx.BitmapButton(panel, -1, buttonOneRouter, pos=(20,340))
    self.buttonOneRouter.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClickRouter)
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

Then you can see that after clicking the buttonOnerouter what actually you are doing is opening a new frame. The left figure is what I get when I run the program, the right one is after I click and enter again my name (I simplified a bit your code. Thats why you only see one button at the bottom instead of 4):

[image]

If you want to put my cat in the canvas instead of  in the button there is still some work to do. I recommend to you to give a look at the wxPython demo. In the miscellaneous group of examples you have one called OGL that shows how to do that.

**Edit:** You can download the wxPython docs and demos package [from here](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php#stable)

Comment: Where can I find the example? I am very gratefull for your help!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is right or not but I suggest you to take this approach and see if it works or not.

Modify your frame class as:

```
def __init(self,parent,id,img=None)

def onClickRouter(self,event):
    image=wx.Image('router.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG)
    temp = image.ConvertToBitmap()
    self.bmp = wx.StaticBitmap(parent=self, bitmap=temp)
    self.frame=bucky(self.bmp)
```

Please let know the outcome.

Comment: I am still having the same problem :( brrrrrrr, Iv been mulling over this for so long.... I just dont understand how I can get a small image to appear on the canvas by clicking a simple button. I can do it in Tkinter but just not Wx. Its crazy